# OkHttp(version:2.4.0) can't enqueue request?

Tags: okhttp

When I  execute multiple  `client.newCall(request).enqueue`... at the same point,
 the callback function onResponse(Response response) return

> "The client failed to send a complete request on this REUSED
>   connection before the timeout period elapsed; 0 bytes were read from
>   client.".

How do deal with this error?  As my http request can't be execute successfully.

Comment: Hello! I faced with the same error, but can't fix it or recognize the reason of this behaviour. I get `Caused by org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 408 Request Timed Out` with the message `The client failed to send a complete request on this REUSED connection before the timeout period elapsed; 0 bytes were read from client.` Do you use any http proxy such as fiddler?